# How to send personalized links in a mail?

Tags: html, forms, email, post, get

I'm setting up a solution  for a backoffice website where the user should be able to send mail for some technician. 
In this mail, the technician must be able to click on a specific button and this will open a new web page with adaptative parameters such as the date, the address, the client name, etc..
To do so, I need to send at least one parameter in the mail (the mission id of this technician) and this parameter must be different in each mail.

I already tried a solution in which the mail is written in HTML and then I could insert a form in the body or a link for a GET request. But it seems that not all the mail server can handle this way of work.

In Gmail it works for everything, but using Safari for Mac OS X, or Outlook messenger it doesn't.

Using POST:

```html
<form action='__the_website_to_post_request__' method='post'>
<input  name='id' type='hidden' value='$id'>
<button type='submit' formmethod='post'>Upload reports</button>
</form>
```

Using GET:

```html
<a href='__the_website_to_post_request__?id=".$id."&tok=".md5($id)."'>
Upload reports
</a>
```

In Outlook, no button appears and in Safari, the post method doesn't work.
Maybe another solution exist doesn't matter which mail application I should use ?

Comment: Normal link (a href) should work everywhere (with plaintext alternative). What do you mean by "doesnt work" (GET)?

Comment: That's the problem, with outlook it doesn't work and doesn't allow it

Comment: We use it in many cases and it does work in all tested enviroments ...

Comment: Forms don't have universal support in emails. Your best bet will be to link to the form and use the parameter from the email to fill those and the rest.